# Bug reports solution

Tags: comparison, bug-tracking

Clarification/summary for the question -- we're looking for:

- a hosted bug tracking system,
- that is as convenient to use as lighthouse/github/launchpad,
- can deal with attachments,
- integrates email notifications and operations (implies operations in commit messages),
- has a script-friendly API,
- allows anonymous bug reports, or ones with an email but that do not require setting up an account for submission.

Lighthouse is close but fails on the last point, launchpad is similar, github also doesn't handle attachments.  Tender is great for the last point, but fails as a general bug tracking system (and it looks like its open-source version will be limited to basically being a forum).

We looked into a number of applications to install and setup -- but with this range of requirements, they are always coming with a huge cost in terms of investing time in setting up and  maintaining a working system.

---

In our (open-source) [project](http://plt-scheme.org/) we have been using Gnats for a really long time.  It doing what it was designed to do fine, but that's getting to be pretty inconvenient: it's no longer maintained, has features that we never use, and lack features that we'd want to use...  It doesn't deal with attachments, has no easy way to perform actions via emails, no integration with commit messages, and a web interface that was designed for 90s browsers.  So I've been looking around in an attempt to find something that could replace it, hopefully some hosted solution to avoid the setup/maintenance hassle.

Probably the most impressive tool that I've seen is [lighthouse](http://lighthouseapp.com/): it has a very nice and practical interface, properly deals with attachments, controllable via emails, and can respond to commands in commit messages.  **But**... It doesn't have any sane way to submit a bug anonymously -- and that's a major requirement, since we need any random user to be able to submit bugs through our IDE.  (It seems that there is a possible hack to forward an email faking the From field, but that doesn't work very well -- specifically, the reporter should be included in the followup email exchange.)  On the other side, there is the related [tender](http://tenderapp.com) tool, which is very good in that area, but is very basic otherwise -- *too* basic to serve as a bug tracking system.

There's a whole bunch of other sites that I've tried -- it seems that all of them require submitters to have an account, so they don't work well for our needs; as well as being limited in various other ways (don't deal with attachments, no good email integration, etc etc).  It doesn't help that the meta-descriptions of these sites is usually pretty obscure: it took me hours to just figure out what tender/lighthouse are and how they're related, and no site mentions its inability to receive bug reports without registration.  (I'm looking only at open-source-friendly sites, since we don't have any kind of budget for such things.)

There's also the option of installing some system locally, but bug tracking systems tend to be monsters that I'd like to avoid configuring and maintaining, if possible.

So the question is: is there anything obvious that I'm missing?  Or to make it more concrete: is there a good comparison page somewhere that lays out popular options and their respective features explicitly?

Comment: Perhaps, if you explain in the question what it is you find "inconvenient" about your current solution, then answers can take that into account.

Comment: Not much to say: it's a project that hasn't been under active development for nearly a decade now.  (I guess that this would be a problem: there's hardly anyone who knows about it...)

Comment: Why not YouTrack! Bugs on a Leash! (It was the associated ad, not sure if it's any good). http://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack

Comment: I really prefer some open-source tool, but in any case, their feature page doesn't even mention "email"...

Comment: You say your current solution is inconvenient. Please edit the question to elaborate on what this means: what is inconvenient and what improvement are you looking for.

Comment: bignose: I did, that was the first edit.

Comment: I think the reality here is that you are going to need to do some programming.  You have very specific needs, and that's why we have general-purpose programming languages.  Pick the open-source solution that's least bad, fire up your text editor, and start hacking!  (FWIW, I think debbugs has a nice email interface.  The web stuff is not exactly modern... but then again, that's a Simple Matter Of Programming to fix.  And I'm sure Debian would appreciate the effort!)

Comment: jrockway: Obviously hacking is an option (and if you tell me about GPLs then my guess is that you didn't actually see what our project is...).  But just like maintenance: that's extra time taken from precious hacking time for things that I really care about.  Currently, given the heavy cost of installation (and the heavier cost of a home-cooked system), we'd just stay with gnats.  The reason for this question is that the delta from something like github/launchpad/lighthouse is small enough that for them it'd probably be trivial -- so my hope was that something like this already exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[JIRA](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) is free for [open source projects](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/licensing.jsp#nonprofit). It's far more user friendly than trac and bugzilla, and allows [anonymous submissions](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Allowing+users+to+create+issues+anonymously) and [plugins](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/JIRA+Plugin+Tutorials). Unfortunately you'll need to host it on your own server, but from personal experience I can tell you that all you need to do is install a database (it can run without; but that's not a good idea) and it basically maintains itself.

Also is there a particular reason why [Google Code](http://code.google.com/projecthosting/) or [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/) issue tracking tools wouldn't work? You don't need to use all their services if you don't want, you could use them purely for issue tracking.

Comment: I looked at JIRA -- and the lack of a hosted solution is a big drawback, since it throws me back into the maintenance loop.  Also, in their own system I didn't see an option for anonymous submissions, and the interface is pretty complicated (bad for a small group with no extra time to deal with a complex system -- that's one of the main problems we have with gnats).

Comment: As for google code, it has the same issue of requiring an account for creating bug reports.  (And I didn't even try sourceforge -- I didn't even see on a quick glance whether they have bug tracking or not -- but I really dislike the idea of having obnoxious ads, being pretty slow, and suffering from general crappiness.)

Comment: JIRA allows anonymous submissions (see the link in my answer), also they allow submissions via email: http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Creating+Issues+and+Comments+from+Email - as far as maintenance goes, we've had an instance running for 5 years, only needed to upgrade it once, and it was just left to itself without problems. It automatically backs up its database for you, and has a GUI to restore it. You're right that it isn't as simple as e.g. Google Code's interface.

Comment: @Andrew yes but not free for open source projects sadly

Comment: Just to clarify, in case someone runs into this question in the future: JIRA is not a good solution because of the problems I mentioned.  (I didn't choose it as an answer, it was the highest voted one at the end of the bounty period.)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/)? It is used by many open source projects.

Comment: Yes, we considered that -- but it's almost as bad as bugzilla, which is why we're looking for a hosted solution.  (Or something that is *really* simple to install and maintain locally, but I doubt that something like that exists.)

Comment: "almost as bad as bugzilla" how? Years ago I installed a number of bug trackers so we could decide on one at my old job. Trac was the hands-down winner. It matches all of your bullet points, so what's the actual problem?

Comment: Take a look at repositoryhosting.com   It is a hosted track solution that works great and very cheap.   Also, JumpBoxes offers the trac and subversion virtual appliances.

Comment: Tom: Installation, maintenance, extension (via (ugh) python).  That's why we really prefer a hosted solution at this point.

Answer (score 2):

[FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/) is one option.  They'll host or you can run it yourself.  My company looked at it but ... political considerations ... meant it is not viable here.

Comment: I looked at that -- it sounded promising, but $30 per user per month makes it a non-option for a non-commercial free open source project.  (I know that there's an option to buy it -- that would cost us about $3500, which is again impractical).

Comment: @Eli: Pretty sure they offer it for free for non-commercial use. "Academic and Non Profit Organizations   Please contact us via email. Fog Creek Software does not offer separate governmental pricing. "

Comment: Tanzelax: where does it say that?  All I've seen is http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/FogBugzOnDemandBilling.html which doesn't mention this at all...

Comment: Update: FogBugz is still expensive -- even after possible discounts.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at this [Comparison of issue tracking systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue_tracking_systems) on Wikipedia?

I have also found [fixx](http://hedgehoglab.com/products/fixx/), by [hedgehoglab](http://hedgehoglab.com/). Apparently it has [the features that you care more](http://hedgehoglab.com/products/fixx/tour/issue-tracking/):

> Get things done
>
> - fixx has an **intuitive** interface to enable quick bug
>     reporting. Filling in a bug report is
>     as **easy** as sending e-mail.
> - Ability to add **multiple attachments** to issues allowing you
>     to attach screenshots and manage
>     documents related to issues.
> - **Clever** notification options to keep relevant people informed while
>     **preventing issue tracker spam**.

Also:

- It has an open [REST API](http://hedgehoglab.com/blog/2009/01/06/fixx-release-fixx-16-released/).
- I see that [you are using Subversion as SCM](http://svn.plt-scheme.org/). There is a [Subversion integration with fixx](http://hedgehoglab.com/blog/2009/04/27/subversion-integration-with-fixx/).
- Its unique [installation requirement is Sun JDK 1.5.0](http://help.hedgehoglab.com/faqs/fixx/installing-fixx).
- It seems free for [Open Source Projects and an hosted version is "Coming soon"](http://hedgehoglab.com/products/fixx/pricing/).

Note that I have never used it, so I cannot give any recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

The open source [BugTracker.NET](http://ifdefined.com/bugtrackernet.html) has support for the following areas that are giving you problems:

- Attachments
- Guest login
- Email notifications
- SVN commit integration

I found it easy to set up, maintain, and tweak. Of course, you might think otherwise if you are not familiar with .NET and have a Windows server available.

Comment: Ugh...  Not only is this not hosted, it looks like the same installation-fest (ASP, .NET, SQL) except that it's on Windows...

Comment: <Not only is this not hosted> That might be a tricky requirement. To be honest, I didn't read your post as carefully as I should have...

Comment: Regarding "but bug tracking systems tend to be monsters that I'd like to avoid configuring and maintaining" and "installation-fet", for folks already comfortable with the Microsoft dev stack of IIS, ASP.NET and SQL Server, BugTracker.NET is easy.  Bug if you aren't already comfortable with the Microsoft tools, then not easy.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at [Unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/).  They do allow an API for the submission of tickets and have your other points covered including attachments.

Comment: I just that, actually, and (AFAICT) it looked like it suffers from the same problem: even if you use the API to create tickets from an application, the reporter will not be CCed on further messages on the bug unless a new account is created.  (And it also looks like such an account counts as a person on the project too.)  It's important for us to have the reporters as part of the following discussion, since our reporters are themselves developers.

Comment: Step 1: receive email.  Step 2: find-or-create account.  Step 3: submit ticket via API.  Step 4: Profit.

Comment: That is too much for average users.  If you're mozilla, then you can just ignore that since you'll have people who will invest the time in submitting bug reports anyway.  But if you're a small project, every user is important, and you don't want reports to drop off just because the (fully justified, IMO) reaction of potential bug submitters is: do I *really* care that much that I'll open yet another account?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [repositoryhosting.com](http://repositoryhosting.com)   They have ready made solution with trac / svn / git, for you. Comes with all kinds of bells and whitsles, such as Agilo plug-in and auotomatic backup to the amazon S3 bucket of your choice.

The prices are very reasonable.

Also, jumboxes offers a Trac / SVN virtual appliance that you can host in your own environment.

Answer (score 0):

[Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) is a good open source option. You can check an [online demo](http://demo.redmine.org/) and a [list of features](http://www.redmine.org/wiki/redmine/Features).

It's **not hosted** though. But it's an interesting option.

And you can always check [a list of different open source bug tracking alternatives](http://www.bugtrackingtools.net/?opensource)

Comment: An easy way to get up and running with Redmine is with the Bitnami installer: http://bitnami.org/stack/redmine.   It installs the whole stack, apache, mysql, ruby, redmine.

Answer (score 0):

I've used ZenDesk in the past and it was rather hassle free.
In addition it has an api: http://www.zendesk.com/api.
Moreover I KNOW it can CC whosoever you want it to whenever anything happens.

Answer (score 0):

We too are looking for a new solution.

At present we're using FogBugz, which is painfully slow.

We need our customers to be able to log bugs via email. Tender looks perfect, with the exception that it doesn't have any obviously usable ID fields that we can pass around. Is there a plugin or similar? I could knock up a browser extension to "goto bug id [whatever]" but that seems kludgy for what should surely be a core feature?

Comment: Our last impression of Tender was that it's too simplistic and can only serve as a kind of a high-level entry point for bugs -- so it's really not what you'd want to use for the internal work around a bug.  (In our case the extra bureaucracy level made it all much less appealing.)

Comment: We ended up going with Tender.
After working with our team we moved more of the bug management into our existing AGILE workflow and now only use Tender for management of customer tickets and expectations. So far so good!